# Why can't I access tkinter objects after importing tkinter as something?

Tags: python, object, tkinter, python-import

I'm following a simple tutorial, learning about the tkinter library. In the tutorial, they do this:

```
 from tkinter import *
 from tkinter import ttk
```

I was told the above is not good practice so instead I did:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

However, later on in the code I have to do something like this:

```
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
```

This gives me an error because I didn't import `ttk` as its own module. I would assume something like this should work:

```
mainframe = tk.ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
```

yet it also gives me an error. How do I access the `ttk` module if `tk.ttk.Frame` is not the way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ttk` is not a part of the `tkinter` module, it is a different file in the tkinter.

In order to import `ttk` you have to do this

```py
import tkinter.ttk as tkk
```

Comment: But if I import the entirety of tkinter, shouldn't I be able to access ttk, since in the second import is literally being imported from tkinter?

Comment: Read this for more info https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html

Comment: You can also import ttk like this : `from tkinter import ttk`